# Import json-simple from Maven failed

Tags: java, json, lib

I'm practicing Java JSON programming using JSON-Simple on [this site](https://docs.jdoodle.com/jdoodle-online-compiler-and-ide/untitled-1) which says:

> All the jars available in maven repo is supported.

**UPDATE:**

So I've now added the external maven library to project.

[image]

But I still can't get it work.

I tried

`import com.googlecode.json-simple.JSONObject;`

but got:

```
error: ';' expected
import com.googlecode.json-simple.JSONObject;
                          ^
```

Then I tried

`import com.googlecode.json_simple.JSONObject;`

but got:

```
error: package com.googlecode.json_simple.parser does not exist
import com.googlecode.json_simple.parser.JSONParser;
                                        ^
```

How to make it works?

Comment: Well... Try then using little older version com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1 and  use import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you forgot to add external maven library to project. Check this out:
[image]

...and enter: org.apache.clerezza.ext:org.json.simple:0.4